# Arrays.asList() vs Collections.singletonList()

Tags: java, collections

Is there an advantage (or much of a difference) to using Arrays.asList(something) over Collections.singletonList(something) to make a list containing one item? The latter makes the returned list immutable as well.

Comment: You can throw Guava's `ImmutableList.of()` and `Lists.newArrayList()` in the mix as well.

Comment: As an aside to this, I have had Collections.singletonList() caused problems when a method returns a List that is later modified downstream.

Comment: Java 10 has true immutable list : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536126/1216775

Comment: This might help: [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000213964-Why-does-Idea-suggest-to-replace-Arrays-asList-o-with-Collections-singletonList-o-)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

`Collections.singletonList(something)` is **immutable** whereas `Arrays.asList(something)` is a fixed size `List` representation of an Array where the List and Array gets joined in the heap.

`Arrays.asList(something)` allows **non-structural changes** made to it, which gets reflected to both the List and the conjoined array. It throws **`UnsupportedOperationException`** for adding, removing elements although you can set an element for a particular index.

Any changes made to the List returned by `Collections.singletonList(something)` will result in **`UnsupportedOperationException`**.

Also, the capacity of the List returned by `Collections.singletonList(something)` will always be **1** unlike `Arrays.asList(something)` whose capacity will be the size of the backed array.

Comment: For some reason the IDE (Android Studio) tells me I should use `Collections.singletonList` instead. Could it really know that it's safe to use it? You write (and according to my tests, it's true) that it could cause an exception if it's being modified (set/remove, for example)...

Answer (score 76):

I would just add that the singletonlist is not backed by an array and just has a reference to that one item. Presumably, it would take less memory and can be significant depending on the number of lists you want to create.

Comment: Any link or code to back this memory efficiency point ? I have this Arrays.asList(ONLY_ONE_OBJECT) written vastly across a codebase and would like to find out if replacing with Collections.singletonList() leads to memory efficiency?

Comment: Arrays.asList references an array (obviously): http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3810


Collections.singletonList: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l4801

Comment: @RahulSaini, when inspecting code, IntelliJ will point out "Call to `Arrays.asList()` with too few arguments under its *performance* category. And the suggestion is to replace it with `Collections.singletonList()`".  I guess this is a good enough indicator that your application performance will improve.

Answer (score 20):

The method `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. The method returns an instance of `ArrayList` which is a **private nested static class** extending `AbstractList` and not `java.util.ArrayList`. This static class provides implementation of few methods e.g. `set, indexOf, forEach, replaceAll` etc. but when we invoke `add` it has no implementation of its own, rather method from `AbstractList` is invoked which throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

The `Collections.singletonList` returns an **immutable list** containing only the specified object and it is serializable as well.

On a side note, for **immutable lists** we generally use `Collections.unmodifiableList` which returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.

```
List<String> srcList = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Mango", "Banana");
var fruits = new ArrayList<>(srcList);
var unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(fruits);     
fruits.set(0, "Apricot");
var modFruit = unmodifiableList.get(0);
System.out.println(modFruit); // prints Apricot
```

An unmodifiable view collection is a collection that is unmodifiable and is also a view onto a backing collection. Note that changes to the backing collection might still be possible, and if they occur, they are visible through the unmodifiable view.

We can have a true immutable list in **Java 10** and later. There are two ways to get **truly unmodifiable list**:

1. `var unmodifiableList = List.copyOf(srcList);`
2. `var unmodifiableList = srcList.stream().collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());` 
   If any of these two variables are used value will still be "Apple" and not "Apricot".

As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of **Java 10**:

> The `List.of` and `List.copyOf` static factory methods provide a
>   convenient way to create unmodifiable lists. The List instances
>   created by these methods have the following characteristics:
>
> 1. They are [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#unmodifiable). Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced. Calling any mutator method on the List will always cause
>      `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown. However, if the contained
>      elements are themselves mutable, this may cause the List's contents to
>      appear to change.
> 2. They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in `NullPointerException`.
> 3. They are serializable if all elements are serializable.
> 4. The order of elements in the list is the same as the order of the provided arguments, or of the elements in the provided array.
> 5. They are `value-based`. Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances. Factories are free to create new
>      instances or reuse existing ones. Therefore, identity-sensitive
>      operations on these instances (reference equality (==), identity hash
>      code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.
> 6. They are serialized as specified on the [Serialized Form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.util.CollSer) page.