# Use Case : Collection.singletonList Vs Collection.unmodifiableList

Tags: java

As I aware that both Collection methods provides read-only access to returned list and throws Exception on modification.

I need to understand Use Cases of both so that when to use singletonList and unmodifiableList.

This might help me to grow understanding of both based on their usage.

Comment: A `singletonList` contains a single element. Didn't you read the documentation?

Comment: I have read doc and after that i have posted Q? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)

Comment: @kayaman What do you mean singleton=single element?

Comment: I didn't write anywhere that `singleton=single element`.

Comment: @kayaman Apology my mistake, then why it is list?

Comment: Because sometimes you need a `List` with a single element inside.

Comment: @kayaman ahh! that's why I am asking real use case in public forum so that other folks experience might help

Comment: If you need to provide a `List` (for example as a parameter to a method), but only have one object to put inside, you can use `singletonList`. Same goes for `emptyList()`.

Answer (score 8):

singletonList takes an item, and creates an immutable list containing only that item. unmodifiableList takes a list, and creates an immutable list that references that list. It is analogous to the difference between add and addAll. One takes an item, one takes a list containing items.

So if you have a `List<...> list`, `singletonList (list).get(0)` returns `list` but `unmodifiableList (list).get(0)` returns `list.get(0)`. And the former is rarely useful.

Comment: Some examples of "rarely useful" could be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801794/use-of-javas-collections-singletonlist