# Is there a standard Java List implementation that doesn't allow adding null to it?

Tags: java, list, collections, null

Say I have a `List` and I know that I never want to add `null` to it. If I am adding null to it, it means I'm making a mistake. So every time I would otherwise call `list.add(item)` I would instead call `if (item == null) throw SomeException(); else list.add(item);`. Is there an existing `List` class (maybe in Apache Commons or something) that does this for me?

Similar question: [Helper to remove null references in a Java List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239579/helper-in-order-to-remove-null-reference-in-java-list) but I don't want to remove all the nulls, I want to make sure they never get added in the first place.

Comment: Couldn't you just subclass the List class and add the functionality you just listed?

Comment: This is a pretty bespoke requirement; `null` is a perfectly acceptable value to hold in a container (in most circumstances).  So you'll probably need to roll your own wrapper.

Comment: @Nick I could, but I would have to override (at least, off the top of my head) `add`, `addAll`, plus a constructor or two. It probably wouldn't be that hard but I suspect someone (Apache, Google...) has already done it, and has caught a subtle bug somewhere that I would likely miss.

Comment: @Oli Well the Collections API is quite clear in allowing a Nullpointer exception in case the collection doesn't support nulls. So clearly the API considers this case and decides otherwise.

Comment: I just happened to discover this: http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/p/org.apache.commons.collections/c/CollectionUtils#addIgnoreNull%28Ljava%2Futil%2FCollection%3BLjava%2Flang%2FObject%3B%29 which doesn't really answer my original question but serves a similar purpose.

Answer (score 33):

Watch out -- several answers here are claiming to solve your problem by wrapping a list and checking in `add` and `addAll`, but they're forgetting you can also add to a `List` via its `listIterator`.  It's challenging to get a constrained list right, which is why Guava has `Constraints.constrainedList` to do it for you.

But before looking at that, first consider whether you only need an *immutable* list, in which case Guava's `ImmutableList` will do that null checking for you anyway.  And in the off chance that you can use one of the JDK's `Queue` implementations instead, that'll do it too.

(Good list of null-hostile collections: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/LivingWithNullHostileCollections)

Comment: Update: `Constraints` has been removed since Guava 16

Answer (score 20):

**Use Apache Commons Collection:**

```
ListUtils.predicatedList(new ArrayList(), PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
```

Adding null to this list throws `IllegalArgumentException`. Furthermore you can back it by any List implementation you like and if necessary you can add more Predicates to be checked.

Same exists for Collections in general.

**Use Google Guava:**

```
Constraints.constrainedList(new ArrayList(), Constraints.notNull())
```

Adding null to this list throws `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there is no standard implementation available in the JDK.  However, the [Collection spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) says that NullPointerException should be thrown when a collection does not support nulls. you can use the following wrapper to add the functionality to any Collection (you'll have to implement the other Collection methods to delegate them to the wrapped instance):

```
class NonNullCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {

    private Collection<T> wrapped;
    public NonNullCollection(Collection<T> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(T item) {
        if (item == null) throw new NullPointerException("The collection does not support null values");
        else wrapped.add(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void addAll(Collection<T> items) {
        if (items.contains(null)) throw new NullPointerException("The collection does not support null values");
        else wrapped.addAll(item);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Yup that's how I'd do it too - apart from the obvious typing error in addAll. Pretty much copy & paste for the other methods, so not much work. +1

Comment: Consider throwing `IllegalArgumentException` as null is an illegal argument. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter

Comment: @Steve Kuo: I only throw NullPointerException because that is what the Collection javadoc says to throw if the Collection does not support nulls.

Comment: This is not terrible, but it's a lot of tedious code like `public T get(int i) { return wrapped.get(i); }`, which is why I was hoping for a one-liner answer like Fatal's.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

If it's ok to create a list and not mutate existing one, [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) added in Java 9 throws NPE when element added is null

Answer (score 4):

This might help you if you want to add an item to the list and silently **ignore** if the value is null:

You need `Apache Commons Collections 4`:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to import:

```java
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
```

Now, use it like:

```java
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
String nullItem = null;
String normalItem = "Text";

CollectionUtils.addIgnoreNull(someList, nullItem);
CollectionUtils.addIgnoreNull(someList, normalItem);
```

Eventually, `someList` will just have `1` item. `null` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Although this problem sort of yells "delegate", it's much easier with subclassing since you intend to inherit almost all the same functionality.

```
class MyList extends List {

  //Probably need to define the default constructor for the compiler

  public add(Object  item) {
    if (item == null) throw SomeException();
    else super.add(item);
  }    

  public addAll(Collection c) {
    if (c.contains(null)) throw SomeException();
    else super.addAll(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: You ought to override addAll as well.

Comment: See my comment to Nick above. Also, I would have to extend a concrete class like ArrayList which means I would have to do all the work all over again if I later needed, say, a LinkedList that didn't allow nulls. So then I think, hm, maybe it should just be a utility method that wraps an existing list, kind of like `Collections.unmodifiableList` is. And then I think, wait, maybe someone has already gone through all this.

Comment: @MatrixFrog See my answer. Apache Commons Collection offers Predicate decorators for Lists and Collections in general. You can back it with List/Collection implementation you like and it is not restricted to check for not null only, but of course it can be used for not null check only.

Answer (score 1):

You might do this by just wrapping an instance of a List and providing the null-checked add method.  In other words, your class would just have a couple of methods and in inner variable.

If you need the full functionality of a list, you might consider Guava's (used to be Google Collections) [ForwardingList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html).

Another approach is to just extend List, but the gotcha there is that you need to override both `add` and `addAll`.

Interestingly, guava has a [standardAddAll](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html#standardAddAll%28int,%20java.lang.Iterable%29), which can be used as the implementation of addAll, which solves at least part of the problem.

Comment: Of course, if you're using Guava you can (and should) just write `Constraints.constrainedList(list, Constraints.notNull())` as Kevin B mentioned in his answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
List<String> list = Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<String>(), String.class);
try {
    list.add(null);
    throw new AssertionError("Expected a NPE");
} catch (NullPointerException expected) {
    System.out.println("list.add(null); threw "+expected);
}
try {
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("", null);
    list.addAll(list2);
    throw new AssertionError("Expected a NPE");
} catch (NullPointerException expected) {
    System.out.println("list.addAll(\"\", null); threw " + expected);
}
```

however a bug in the addAll implementation means you need to use the following

```
List<String> list = Collections.checkedList(
   Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<String>(), String.class), String.class);
```

and you get

```
list.add(null); threw java.lang.NullPointerException
list.addAll("", null); threw java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Isn't that actually a bug in the `add` implementation? As I said on mP's answer, the doc says: "Since null is considered to be a value of any reference type, the returned list permits insertion of null elements whenever the backing list does." http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.util/c/Collections So it seems to me that `add` is right and `addAll` is wrong.

Comment: I agree its inconsistent with the javadoc. The typeCheck code just does `if(!type.isIntance(o))` there is no special handling for `null` to allow it. Personally this is the behaviour I would want.

Comment: I guess I would agree that it's what I would want; I'm not sure. But I'm inclined to think that in future Java releases, the docs will stay the same and the code will change to match the docs, not the other way around, right? If `checkedList` worked exactly the way the docs say it does, then `checkedList(x)` and `checkedList(checkedList(x))` would both allow adding nulls, if x allowed adding nulls. So that means upgrading to a newer version of Java would change the behavior of this code.

Comment: @MatrixFrog, I would agree that it happens to work now, possibly due to a bug.  I have reported it as an issue to the Java Bug Database so it could be changed soon. If you want to track Null values perhaps you can use an approach like IntelliJ does http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html It instruments runtime checks, but also does static analysis.

Comment: Cool. Do you have a link to that bug so I can track its progress?

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7057808 no sure how long it takes before you can see it.

Comment: Just noticed my first comment is wrong. I meant to say: "So it seems to me that `add` is wrong and `addAll` is right." Though in fact both methods are wrong. See my comment on the bug page...

Comment: That bug's been known for years; I doubt they'll fix it.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion I think it's fixed by the report.

Comment: THIS NO LONGER WORKS. In Java 11 (maybe earlier versions too) the `add` and `addAll` methods explicitly check and allow for `null` before using instanceof.

Answer (score -1):

try Collections.checkedList().

Comment: I don't think that helps. "Since null is considered to be a value of any reference type, the returned list permits insertion of null elements whenever the backing list does." http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.util/c/Collections

Comment: This collection does an isInstance which prevent nulls being added.  A bug in the code allows nulls to be added with addAll().  The workaround is to wrap the collection twice. ;)