# Ensuring Generic Type cannot be null

Tags: java, generics, notnull

Is it possible to do something like `class Foo<@NotNull T>` or `new Foo<@NotNull Bar>` where the first one states that for all instances of `Foo` the value in the generic cannot be null and the second one states that for that instance of `Foo` it's generic value cannot be null?

Comment: What do you mean _cannot be null_? Do you mean absent, as in a raw type?

Comment: As in if I were to have a list any value added to the list cannot be null.

Comment: That's not something you can do with type declarations. Enforce it wherever a value of the type parameter is expected.

Comment: nulls are baked into the language. null is a valid reference to pass in to any method that accepts an object.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433478/is-there-a-standard-java-list-implementation-that-doesnt-allow-adding-null-to-i