# Spring mvc ignore null objects in list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I handle null objects in array which binds from an inputs?
I have

input name=example value=3,4
input name=example value=""

List example = new ArrayList()

the bind result is a list with 3 elements = null ,3, 4 is there an attribute that I can put on the list to ignore this null?

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) isn't working.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433478/is-there-a-standard-java-list-implementation-that-doesnt-allow-adding-null-to-i

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send your list to Apache ListUtils:

```
List result = ListUtils.predicatedList(example, PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classic [Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), it will look like this:

```
list = list.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```