# What are the java collections accepts adding null values?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I know Set and Map accepts null values and today I just found out LinkedList also accepts null values like

```
   map.put(null, 1);
   set.add(null);
   linkedList.add(null)
```

Is there any other collections that allow null values to be stored?. Just posting to get a comprehensive list in one place and reason for each for them.

Comment: "I know Set and Map accepts null values" -- not necessarily; implementations of these interfaces are free to reject null values.

Comment: @dnault there are example [since java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62826234/1059372)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Set` and `Map` are interfaces. They have several implementations in Java.

Popular implementations of the `Map` are:

1. `HashMap` - accepts one `null` key
2. `Hashtable` - doesn't accept any `null` key
3. `TreeMap` - doesn't accept any `null` key
4. `LinkedHashMap` - accepts one `null` key

Any number of `null` values can be added as *value* in any of above implementations

---

Popular implementations of the `Set` are:

1. `HashSet` - accepts one `null` element
2. `TreeSet` - doesn't accept any `null` element
3. `LinkedHashSet` - accepts one `null` element

---

Any implementations of `List`, like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` can accept `null`s.

Comment: Without a doubt, it's true the popular List implementations accept null values. However, the [documentation for List.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) say, "Lists that support this operation may place limitations on what elements may be added to this list. In particular, some lists will refuse to add null elements...". It goes on to say, "List classes should clearly specify in their documentation any restrictions on what elements may be added." So, when in doubt, consult the Javadoc.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433478/is-there-a-standard-java-list-implementation-that-doesnt-allow-adding-null-to-i

Comment: Note that it's "Hashtable" with a lowercase T in Java.

Comment: How to remember it in logical way rather than literally letters one by one

Answer (score 3):

Accepting `null`s was a design mistake, as time has proven. First of all this complicates implementations, because at some point in time you might need to be able to compare `null` to `null`, for example; and this sometimes require special handling (or special branches in the code at least).

Since java-9, immutable collections all reject `null` and even document it properly. One minor example (but there are many more) is `Set:of`, that says:

> @throws NullPointerException if the element is null

Not only that, but they also don't allow `null` checks, so you might be surprised by this a bit:

```
    Set<Object> oldS = new HashSet<>();
    oldS.add(new Object());
    System.out.println(oldS.contains(null)); // false

    Set<Object> newS = Set.of(new Object());
    System.out.println(newS.contains(null)); // NPE
```

Every new collection or implementation that comes to JDK prohibits `null`.

Comment: Well, I don't completely agree here. Yes, `null`s are rarely useful in any collection; however, I've seen several times they were used deliberately for implementing different algorithms.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri the fact that `HashMap` allows a `null` key is still exploited by different algorithms. Or the fact that it had some traversal order until java-8 was used by many people too, nevertheless both were admitted as mistakes by `HasMap` creators.

Comment: Can you provide any reference where `HashMap` creators say that?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri [here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJrIMv4dAek&t=31m9s) : _generally regarded as a mistake_. You do know who Stuart Marks is, right? This is (1) and (2) is the fact that when you admit a mistake you do not it again (that is why immutable collections prohibit it)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be resolved by using placeholder class `Optional` from JDK.

The principle is to package a nullable value within an wrapper instance using Optional class that will carry values (null values also).

It can be annoying and little heavy in the code but surely can be suitable in many cases.

**Here is an example with a non-null value :**

```java
Optional<Integer> valuedInt = Optional.ofNullable(123);
assertTrue(valuedInt.isPresent());          
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(123), valuedInt.get());
```

**Here is an example with a null value :**

```java
Optional<Integer> nullInt = Optional.ofNullable(null);
assertTrue(nullInt.isEmpty());
try {
    var val = nullInt.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Invocation of nullInt.get() throws an exception.
    assertTrue(e instanceof NoSuchElementException);
}
            
// However, the method Optional.orElse(T) can be used as
// a getter that supplies the value wether it is valued or null.
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(123), valuedInt.orElse(null));
assertEquals(null,                 nullInt.orElse(null));
```

**We can initialize a list as so :**

```java
// Our hacked list
List<Optional<Integer>> integersOpt;
```

**First way to populate the list :**

```java
integersOpt = new ArrayList<>();
integersOpt.add(Optional.ofNullable(1));
integersOpt.add(Optional.ofNullable(null));
integersOpt.add(Optional.ofNullable(2));
integersOpt.add(Optional.ofNullable(null));
integersOpt.add(Optional.ofNullable(3));
```

**Second way to populate the list (unmodifiable) :**

```java
integersOpt =
    Arrays.asList(1, null, 2, null, 3).stream()
    .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Third way to populate the list (modifiable) :**

```java
integersOpt =
    new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(1, null, 2, null, 3).stream()
        .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
```

**Count and print values :**

```java
int countNulls = 0, countNonNulls = 0;
for(Optional<Integer> opt : integersOpt) {
    Integer optVal = opt.orElse(null); // Our famous "getter" function.
    if(optVal == null) {countNulls++;}
    else               {countNonNulls++;}
    System.out.println("Original value = " + optVal);
}

assertEquals(2, countNulls);
assertEquals(3, countNonNulls);
```

`integersOpt.toString()` will return this value :

```java
[Optional[1], Optional.empty, Optional[2], Optional.empty, Optional[3]]
```