# What is the use of singletonList?

Tags: java, list, collections

I was looking around for some elegant solution to removing null values from a List. I came across the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239631/423969), which says I can use  `list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));`

This, however, throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, which I'm assuming is because `removeAll()` is attempting to do some mutative operation on the immutable singleton collection. Is this correct?

If this is the case, what would be a typical use of this `singletonList`? To represent a collection of size 1 when you're sure you don't want to actually do anything with the collection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you have declared the list? Using Arrays.asList() ? If so then it will be immutable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works like a charm:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add(null);
list.add("def");
list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
System.out.println(list);  //[abc, def]
```

Indeed `Collections.singletonList(null)` is immutable (which is unfortunately hidden in Java<sup>[1]</sup>), but the exception is thrown from your `list` variable. Apparently it is immutable as well, like in example below:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", null, "def");
list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
```

This code *will* throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. So as you can see `singletonList()` is useful in this case. Use it when client code expects a read-only list (it won't modify it) but you only want to pass one element in it. `singletonList()` is (thread-)safe (due to immutability), fast and compact.

<sup>[1]</sup> E.g. in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) there is a separete hierarchy for mutable and immutable collections and API can choose whether it accept this or the other (or both, as they have common base interfaces)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I was unaware that `Arrays.asList()` returns an immutable list (although I do remember reading that it was "backed by the array that is passed into it"). This can be fixed by using the constructor of `ArrayList(Collection c)`:

`new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(someArray)).removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null))`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question :

> what would be a typical use of this singletonList? To represent a collection of size 1 when you're sure you don't want to actually do anything with the collection?

The typical use is if you have one element and want to pass it to a method that accepts a `List`, ie

```
public void registerUsers(List<User> users) {...}

User currentUser = Login Manager.getCurrentUser();
registerUsers(Collections.singletonList(currentUser));
```

The `removeAll()` is a special case for this.

Answer (score 1):

Has your list been protected with

```java
Collections.unmodifiableList(list)
```

Because if you have protected it and try to modify it later you get that error.